# Parsing (from text) a table with two-row header

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm parsing the output of a .ipynb. The output was generated as plain text (using print) instead of a dataframe (not using print), in the spirit of:

```
print( athletes.groupby('NOC').count() )
```

I came up with hacks (e.g. using `pandas.read_fwf()`) to the various cases, but I was wondering if anyone has an idea for a more elegant solution.

---

It keeps nagging me that it's weird (bad design?) that the default print of a pandas.dataframe can't be parsed by pandas.

---

EDIT: added more examples to the first table

Table 1

```
                            Name  Discipline
NOC                                         
United States of America     615         615
Japan                        586         586
Australia                    470         470
People's Republic of China   401         401
Germany                      400         400
```

Table 2

```
                                     Name
NOC                      Discipline
United States of America Athletics    144
Germany                  Athletics     95
Great Britain            Athletics     75
Italy                    Athletics     73
Japan                    Athletics     70
Bermuda                  Triathlon      1
Libya                    Athletics      1
Palestine                Athletics      1
San Marino               Swimming       1
Kiribati                 Athletics      1
```

Table 3

```
                       Name       NOC Discipline
1410             CA Liliana  Portugal  Athletics
1411   CABAL Juan-Sebastian  Colombia     Tennis
1412        CABALLERO Denia      Cuba  Athletics
1413  CABANA PEREZ Cristina     Spain       Judo
1414          CABECINHA Ana  Portugal  Athletics
```

Comment: Have you tested `pandas.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following input:

```
text = '''                            Name  Discipline
NOC                                         
United States of America     615         615
Japan                        586         586
Australia                    470         470
People's Republic of China   401         401
Germany                      400         400'''
```

You can use `pandas.read_csv` with the '\s\s+' separator:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
```

Output:

```
>>> df.index
Index(['United States of America', 'Japan', 'Australia',
       'People's Republic of China', 'Germany'],
      dtype='object', name='NOC')

>>> df.columns
Index(['Name', 'Discipline'], dtype='object')

>>> df
                            Name  Discipline
NOC                                         
United States of America     615         615
Japan                        586         586
Australia                    470         470
People's Republic of China   401         401
Germany                      400         400
```

Comment: It just occurred to me the double space, and I was trying sep='\s{2,}' with read_fwf(), which didn't seem to work. Then, I saw your post. It looks like a major step in the right direction, but please take a look at my second table that I added. Due to the double row, it seems that only the first header row counts, and the parser gets confused later. Probably need to combine the two headers rows before that.

Comment: The issue here is that you don't have a double space between 'America' and 'Athletics', so the format is ambiguous.

Comment: Right, I was too tired to catch it. I still liked your answer.